# interpolating and difference table, an old mid exam?!

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, numerical-methods

For calculating divided (fraction) difference table for interpolating the points $(x_i, f_i)$, $i=1,2,...,n$; by using a polynomial with degree lower or equal to $n$, how many fraction was used?

> I) $n(n-1)/2$
>
> II) $n(n+1)/2$

This is an old midterm exam on numerical method. I think I is true, but my TA says II is true. How can solve this challenging tricky question ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n$ data points, you start with $n-1$ divided differences, this reduces by one at each level, resulting in the sum $(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1$ which gives I.

It may be that your TA "sees" $i=0,1,2,...,n$, as it is often done in interpolation tasks with a degree-$n$ interpolating polynomial. Then there are $n+1$ points and II gives the amount of divisions.